# Solve the linear homogeneous recurrence relation with constant coefficients

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

$$9a_{n} = 6a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}, a_{0}=6, a_{1}=5$$

So

$$x^n = (6x^{n-1}-x^{n-2})\div9$$

thus

$$[x^2 = (6x-1)\div9] \equiv [x^2 - \frac{2}{3}x + \frac{1}{9} = 0], x=\frac{1}{3}$$

also

$$a_{2}=\frac{8}{3}, a_{3}=\frac{31}{27}$$

How do I plug in that x/root to solve for the given recurrence relation?

I tried

$$9a_{n} = 6(\frac{1}{3})^{n-1} - (\frac{1}{3})^{n-2}$$

which for n=1 gives 5... which is correct, for a_1 though, not 9a_1? So that's not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $a_n=c\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n+dn\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n$, $a_0=2\implies c=6$ and $a_1=5\implies d=9$, so

$\displaystyle a_n=\frac{6}{3^n}+\frac{9n}{3^n}=\frac{2+3n}{3^{n-1}}$

Comment: thank you but what is this d.

Comment: c and d are arbitrary constants, and then we can use $a_0$ and $a_1$ to solve for them.

Comment: Since there is a repeated root, the general solution to the recurrence has the form $a_n=c(r^n)+dn(r^n)$ where c and d are constants and r is the repeated root.

Comment: awesome thanks. that's only for repeated root cases though? so like if there were 2 distinct roots i wouldn't follow this formula?

Comment: I am just canceling a common factor of 3 on the top and bottom after combining the two fractions.

Comment: Yes, you're right; you would only use this in the case of a repeated root.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps
$$
a_{0}=6
$$
$$
a_{1}=5
$$
$$
9a_{n} = 6a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}
$$
Lets rewrite this recurrence as
$$
a_{n} = \frac69a_{n-1}-\frac19a_{n-2}
$$
$$
a_{n} = \frac23a_{n-1}-\frac1{3^2}a_{n-2}
$$
Now let's multiply by $3^n$
$$
3^0a_{0}=3^06=6
$$
$$
3^1a_{1}=3^15=15
$$
$$
3^na_{n} = 2\cdot 3^{n-1}a_{n-1}-3^{n-2}a_{n-2}
$$
Let $S_n=3^na_n$, then
$$
S_0=6
$$
$$
S_{1}=15
$$
$$
S_n= 2S_{n-1}-S_{n-2}
$$
It follows that
$$
S_n= S_1n-S_0(n-1)=9n+6=3(3n+2)
$$
Therefore

> $$
> a_n=\frac{3(3n+2)}{3^n}=3^{1-n}(3n+2)
> $$